# Profiling an app in vs2010 fails with an error Message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiler

In visual studio 2010, I tried to profile a new winforms app (a fresh app with  zero code added by me).

But the profiling (.Net Memory Allocation (Sampling)) but it fails with the following mesaage.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/796a701cc1.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/796a701cc1.jpg)

This is what the output window spits out after this error message

```
Profiling started.
Profiling process ID 3332 (WindowsFormsApplication1).
Process ID 3332 has exited.
Data written to D:\Finder.Net\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1100702(3).vsp.
Profiling finished.
PRF0025: No data was collected. 
Profiling complete.
```

Is this my fault. Am I doing something wrong here

Comment: What app are you using for profiling? Is there anything in the vsp file that it mentions?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error, rebooted the machine, which was the solution that many forums gave, but to no avail. The problem with my test was that it was throwing an exception. Once I fixed it, the profiler ran successfully. So my suggestion is run the tests without the profiler first and once you are all green, kick in the profiler.